# How to read postfix maillog

Tags: email, postfix, logging, centos7

My centos server is getting too many of the following log in the /var/log/maillog

```
Apr 12 05:07:44 gaboli-vm-live postfix/error[5597]: AC01D2988FA6: to=<gaurav.agrawal@gaboli.com>, relay=none, delay=274343, delays=274343/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c08::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

What does this mean? Is there any tutorial which describe each of these parameters (relay, delay, status etc)?

Comment: Type `man postfix` into your terminal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Postfix looked up the `gaboli.com` domain of the recipient and found a DNS MX record saying that mail for this domain can be delivered to the mail server at `ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com`
- Postfix tried to connect to that mail server's **IPv6** address `2607:f8b0:4001:c08::1a` but could not reach it. It is likely that your own configuration or your own network does not support IPv6 and Postfix was (by default) configured to use both IPv4 and IPv6. Correcting your IPv6 setup or just restricting Postfix to IPv4 will probably prevent these errors.

  - Edit the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and specify `inet_protocols = ipv4`
    and then restart the Postfix server.
  - To keep using IPv6 you need to at least make sure that your Postfix server has a DNS AAAA record with your IPv6 address and that this IPv6 address also has a reverse DNS record pointing to your Postfix server.
- The `relay=none` part of the log line indicates that there was no connection to the destination server, otherwise it would have read something like `relay=ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2607:f8b0:4001:c08::1a]:25`
- The `delay=274343` part means that your message has now spent 274343 seconds (more than three days) on your Postfix server.
- The `delays=274343/0/0/0` part specifies more details as stipulated by Feature 20051103 in some very old [Postfix 2.3 relase notes](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/RELEASE_NOTES-2.3):

  1. The first number is the time on the server before entering the message queue. For a deferred message like this, it is the sum of delays of all previous attempts to deliver the message.
  2. The second number is the time spent in the queue.
  3. The third number is the connection setup time including DNS, HELO and TLS.
  4. The fourth number is usually the time that the message took to go from your Postfix server to the destination mail server, or sometimes the time after which the connection timed-out or in this specific case zero because there was never a connection.
- The `dsn=4.4.1` part indicates the status code of the appropriate Delivery Status Notification as described by [RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463) to be (**4**.x.x) a temporary situation (x.**4**.x) due to a network or routing problem causing (x.**4.1**) no answer from the host.
- The `status=deferred` part indicates that this delivery attempt did not succeed but Postfix will try again later.